# errors when defining the path to a video file stored on the Sd Card

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, filepath

I am having a problem declaring the path to a video file correctly.
I have looked at plenty of different resources and they all say pretty much the same thing which is this...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView infinnittiVid = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    infinnittiVid.setVideoPath("/SdCard/infinnitti.mp4");

    MediaController infinnittiController = new MediaController(this);
    infinnittiVid.setMediaController(infinnittiController);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

No matter what I do I get an error on the device "Can't play this video"
I know that I shouldn't hard code the string...
The issue seems to be with the address. I have tried multiple formats and they play in the gallery app but this code never works. I have messed around with the path to confirm my suspicion that this is the problem and I always get the same error and no logical alterations to the path will give me a working VideoView.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem

infinnittiVid.setVideoPath("/SdCard/infinnitti.mp4");

it should be like this

```
  String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    path=path+"/infinnitti.mp4";

Uri mUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
infinnittiVid.setVideoURI(mUri);
```

Comment: I thought that the solution would look like that because Eclipse has been asking me to use:
`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();`


But I wasn't sure how to declare it.

I still get the same error with this code though on a Samsung Tablet.


I get this error in LogCat
E/MediaPlayer(8868): error (1, -2147483648)

Comment: Yeah now I have it set like this:



    `VideoView infinnittiVid = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);  
        String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        path=path+"/infinnitti.mp4";  
        
        Uri mUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));  
        infinnittiVid.setVideoURI(mUri);  
        
        MediaController infinnittiController = new MediaController(this);  
        infinnittiVid.setMediaController(infinnittiController);  
    }
`



But I get the same on device error "Can't Play this video"
It's so stubborn!!

Comment: I would assume it was an incompatible format if I hadn't seen it play in the native gallery. I have looked at lots of different methods for playing video and I can't find any that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Their are Two ways

First

```
String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
infinnittiVid.setVideoPath(path+"/infinnitti.mp4");
```

Second

```
VideoView infinnittiVid = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
infinnittiVid.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/infinnitti.mp4");
```

Comment: Yeah same thing...
Both of these look like they should work but I always get the same error on the device.
I would have assumed that it was the device failing to decode the video if I hadn't seen it play on the gallery app.